# How to drag a SKSpriteNode without touching it with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to move SKSpriteNode horizontally by dragging. To get the idea of what I try to achieve you can [watch this](https://youtu.be/5zBIdVtCz4k). I want player to be able to drag sprite without touching it. But I don't really know how to implement it correctly. 
I tried to do something like:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    capLeft.size = self.capLeft.size
    self.capLeft.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + self.capLeft.size.height * 2, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.capLeft.size.height * 1.5)
    capLeft.zPosition = 1

    self.addChild(capLeft)

    let panLeftCap: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: capLeft, action: Selector("moveLeftCap:"))
```

And when I'm setting a moveLeftCap function, code that I've found for UIPanGestureRecognizer is requiring "View" and gives me an error. I also wanted to limit min and max positions of a sprite through which it shouldn't go.
  Any ideas how to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably get that error because you can't just access the view from any node in the tree. You could to refer to it as scene!.view or you handle the gesture within you scene instead which is preferable if you want to keep things simple.

I gave it a try and came up with this basic scene:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var shape:SKNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //creates the shape to be moved
        shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30.0)
        shape.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, frame.midY)
        addChild(shape)

        //sets up gesture recognizer
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panned:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    var previousTranslateX:CGFloat = 0.0

    func panned (sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        //retrieve pan movement along the x-axis of the view since the gesture began
        let currentTranslateX = sender.translationInView(view!).x

        //calculate translation since last measurement
        let translateX = currentTranslateX - previousTranslateX

        //move shape within frame boundaries
        let newShapeX = shape.position.x + translateX
        if newShapeX < frame.maxX && newShapeX > frame.minX {
            shape.position = CGPointMake(shape.position.x + translateX, shape.position.y)
        }

        //(re-)set previous measurement
        if sender.state == .Ended {
        previousTranslateX = 0
        } else {
            previousTranslateX = currentTranslateX
        }
    }
}
```

when you move you finger across the screen, the circle gets moves along the x-axis accordingly.

if you want to move the sprite in both x and y directions, remember to invert the y-values from the view (up in view is down in scene).

Comment: Man, that's awesome! it's working perfectly. I  just wanted to ask: if I want to limit its movement just before frame.midX - how to do it better?  And I also want to setup a second node right after frame.midX and drag it by the same principals. So if player makes a pan on the left side of the screen - he is moving left node, and right node if he is panning on the right side. How to limit gestures like so?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b65ec85bd601329646d9) should do it. However, you can only control one node at a time. This is due to the limitations of the pan gesture recogniser. If you need to control them at the same time you should not use the touch recogniser but handle the touches yourself (touchesBegan method). If you really want to use the recogniser, i think it should also be possible to add two separate views above your skview with each one having it's own pan recognizer. good luck with your game!

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me any link where I can find an example of how to make it via touchesBegan and swift?

Comment: I figured it out. [Here](https://gist.github.com/densmoe/7fb22ef64f7a142d4050) you go! I hope it helps.  Edit: link was broken

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it!